# Working with HTML select in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am developing my first Angular application. My page contains textbox & html select element. I bind that select element using

```
 <select data-ng-model="ddlLocation">
      <option value="">--Select--</option>
      <option data-ng-repeat="location in vm.arrLocations" value="{{location.srNo}}">{{location.name}}</option>
 </select>
```

On controller side, i populate arrLocations as

```
 this.getLocationsOnSuccess = function (response) {
        //vm.locations = response.data; 
        var arrLocations = new Array();

        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
            vm.locationSrNo = response[i].srNo;
            vm.locationName = response[i].name;

            arrLocations.push({
                srNo: response[i].srNo,
                name: response[i].name
            });  
        }

        vm.arrLocations = arrLocations;
    }
```

To get default value selected :

```
vm.ddlLocation = "--Select--";
```

Now how to get selected value on button click. 
Is there any alternate approach for CRUD functionality with HTML select in Angular JS?

Comment: u can use ng-change function and pass your model to that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at [NgOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) which is a great feature in angularjs. 
To implement this in your example

```
<select ng-model="ddlLocation" ng-options="location as location.name for location in vm.arrLocations">
      <option value="">--Select--</option>
 </select>
```

The location gets bind to the option value and the location.name gets displayed in the option text. 
The "--Select--" will be selected as default as the ddlLocation is null.

When a option is selected the location value of the option will be the value of the NgModel ddlLocation.

To get the value of the selected option you just use the ng-model value ddlLocation which will hold the selected location object.
 In your controller you get it as:

```
$scope.randomFunc = function(){
    var value = $scope.ddlLocation.value;
    var name =  $scope.ddlLocation.name;
 };
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
this.getLocationsOnSuccess = function (response) {
    //vm.locations = response.data; 
    var arrLocations = new Array();

    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
        vm.locationSrNo = response[i].srNo;
        vm.locationName = response[i].name;

        arrLocations.push({
            srNo: response[i].srNo,
            name: response[i].name
        });  
    }

    vm.arrLocations = arrLocations;

    vm.whatIsMyValue = function() {
        alert(vm.ddLocation);
    }
}
```

and in your HTML :

```
<button ng-click="whatIsMyValue()"></button>
```

It will display your value. As you can see, you can now use it as you want.

Comment: I already tried using vm.ddlLocation on controller But it will always return default option ie '--Select--'

Comment: well that's because you need to put `vm.ddLocation` in your select, as you did with other variables.

Comment: "you need to put vm.ddLocation in your select "
Means??

Comment: `<select data-ng-model="vm.ddlLocation">` @UmeshAP

Comment: Silly mistake while coding. Now code works as expected. Thanks for pointing out.